# Declaring new math function using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

A simple issue:

Why does

```
import numpy as np
f = np.sin(x)
print(f(0.3))
```

return an error; whereas

```
import numpy as np
print(np.sin(0.3))
```

does not?

Suppose, for instance I wanted to store f as:

```
f(x) = sin(x) + 2*sin(3.4*x)
```

How would I go about this? Apologies if this question is too simple - perhaps I should have posted it on StackExchange.

Comment: `f` is a number not a function

Comment: `def f(x):  ...` is the normal way in python for defining a function.  There isn't a special way for math in numpy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `lambda` function, if I understand your uses correctly:

```
f = lambda x: np.sin(x) + np.sin(3.456 * x)
print(f(0.3))
```

Some more details on `lambda` if you're unfamiliar can be found [here](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2011/08/29/lambda_tutorial/)

Comment: This is actually considered not Pythonic by PEP 8. Named lambdas are frowned upon. Instead you should use `def`.

Comment: Thank you very much - I really appreciate the specific answer and lack of condescension! I will post in StackExchange in the future for simple questions.

Comment: @DeepSpace true, but PEP 8 is more what you'd call "guidelines" than actual rules (unashamed Pirates of the Caribbean reference)

Answer (score 1):

`f = np.sin(x)` assigns the return value of `np.sin(x)` (which can't even be calculated because `x` is not defined) to `f`. Even if `x` was defined, `f(0.3)` would have failed since a float is not callable.

You meant to do `f = np.sin`.

```
import numpy as np

f = np.sin
print(f(0.3))
# 0.295520206661
```

Comment: Excellent - thank you.
Suppose I were looking store sin(x) + sin(3.456x) - is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: @AndrewWhelan Yes, you can use `def`: `def f(x): return sin(x) + sin(3.4 * x)`